# Hide position in "Developer Story"

Tags: discussion, support, developer-story

There is a position that I do not find relevant to the position I am applying. The only option I can find is to delete the item, which is what I do not want to do.

Is it possible to temporary hide the position?

Comment: A public/private checkbox could be useful on each item, really.

Comment: While it my not be relevant on this platform, it may prompt a conversation about the gap in employment which would lead up to having to explain the position anyway as well as why it was left off. Unless you were working multiple jobs or this timeframe wasn't that significant in duration.

Comment: It might not be as relevant for Positions, but I can see times I would want to hide open-source work. Maybe you contributed to a competitor, or a project ideologically opposed to the company. If I am applying to Lizard Inc, I might not want to advertise my contributions to Frogs on Github.

Comment: Also, today I wanted to get the PDF version of the SO CV and to my surprise it is 5 pages long. I'd like to hide some stuff, so that I can stay within 2 pages, but I still want them on the developer story to have a completely detailed history of my career.

Comment: @Kjir yes. IMHO, it is crucial to tailor the CV for each position. Without being able to opt-out parts of it, the CV looks vague.